# Raspberry Pi wired Ethernet keeps disconnecting

Tags: raspberry-pi

Hi when I boot up my Raspberry Pi it stays connected for about 2 minutes but suddenly disconnects. It does not reconnect unless I reboot it. Please help.

Comment: note if you don't get an answer here there is a SE for the pi.... http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is the light on the cable jack going out when this happens? If not, does the output of `ifconfig` change? What is the output? Does `ifup eth#` fix it (where # is the interface number which is failing)? If all else fails check `lspci -v` to see if the card itself is disappearing.

Comment: Is it static IP or dynamic IP for the Raspberry Pi? Post the output of ifconfig command when it is connected and when it is disconnected. Post the /etc/network/interfaces file of the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

Most networking problems with Raspberry Pi's are solved by using a different power supply.

Especially the model B, which can draw significantly over the 700 mA which many power supplies provide. Connecting all USB devices to a hub which has a separate power supply can also help matters.

Answer (score -1):

This completely solved my issues after months of continuous disconnections (every few seconds sometimes)

```
sudo ethtool --set-eee eth0 eee off
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Could you please write something on how this solves the problem? Just posting uncommented commands is not a good style for answers.